# Unable to reflect. Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, reflection

I have two different classes one is with validating method bellow.

```
@Validator
public boolean validIdentifier() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
        boolean flag=false;
        Field[] fields=this.data.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields) {
            if (!field.isAccessible()){
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }       
            if (field.getName().endsWith("Identifier") && field.get(data)!=null){
                flag=true;
                field.setAccessible(false);
                break;
            }
            field.setAccessible(false);
        }
        return flag;
}
```

The other one has two methods that reflect on the above validating method like this

```
public void validate(){
  AppValidator validator=new AppValidator(somebean);
  doCommonValidation(validator.getClass());
}

public void doCommonValidation(Class clazz){
        Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
        for(Method method:methods) {
            for(Annotation annotation:method.getAnnotations()){
                try {
                    if (annotation instanceof Validator && !(boolean)method.invoke(clazz)){ //exception is here
                        String errorMessage = ((Validator)annotation).message();
                        String display=((Validator)annotation).displayField();
                        if(errorMessage != null) {
                            System.out.println(display+":"+errorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                        | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

The above code throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class.

If I change doCommonValidation and by-pass validate method like this, everything works.

```
public void validate() {
        try {
            AppValidator validator=new AppValidator(someBean);
            Method[] methods = validator.getClass().getMethods();           
            for(Method method:methods) {
                for(Annotation annotation:method.getAnnotations()){
                    if (annotation instanceof ValidatingMethod && !(boolean)method.invoke(validator)){
                        String errorMessage = ((ValidatingMethod)annotation).message();
                        String display=((ValidatingMethod)annotation).displayField();
                        if(errorMessage != null) {
                            System.out.println(display+":"+errorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
}
```

The issue is that I do need to be able to plugin several different validating classes. If I explicilty instanciate them then I have to write repeating code where the only diffirence is the class that I reflect on.

I don't understand why in the first case I get the exception and in the second I don't. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute this line in the erroneous case:

```
if (annotation instanceof Validator && !(boolean)method.invoke(clazz))
```

you need to pass to the `invoke` method a parameter representing the object on which to invoke the method, as it is an instance method. This parameter should be of type denoted by the `Class` instance passed as parameter to the `doCommonValidation(Class)` method. What you pass is an instance of `Class<T>`, rather than an instance of .

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The worst thing was that the answer was in front of me all the time!

I need to invoke method on the object not the class. Hence validate method should look like this.

```
public void validate(){
  AppValidator validator=new AppValidator(somebean);
  doCommonValidation(validator);
}
```

and doCommonValidation method should look like this

```
public void doCommonValidation(Object obj){
    Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();
    for(Method method:methods) {
        for(Annotation annotation:method.getAnnotations()){
        try {
            if (annotation instanceof Validator && !(boolean)method.invoke(obj)){ 
            String errorMessage = ((Validator)annotation).message();
            String display=((Validator)annotation).displayField();
            if(errorMessage != null) {
                System.out.println(display+":"+errorMessage);
            }
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}
```